# Is there a way to make this Python Tkinter function display numbers with some kind of delay effect?

Tags: python, tkinter, visualization, delay, sudoku

I'm developing a simple Python GUI app to solve sudokus using Tkinter. My problem currently is that I've tried apparently all possible ways to add a little delay to the displaying of the solving numbers while the backtracking algorithm finds them, so as to get a visual effect on the grid (just like [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Sudoku_solved_by_bactracking.gif)).

Here is the code:

```
#F to solve puzzle
def solve_sudoku():
    find = find_empty()
    if not find_empty():
        return True
    else:
        x, y = find
    for num in range(1, 10):
        if validate_cell(x, y, num):
            sudoku[x][y].delete(0, "end")
            sudoku[x][y].insert(0, str(num))
            sudoku[x][y].config(fg = "SpringGreen3")
            #===> here goes the delay <===
            if solve_sudoku():
                return True
            sudoku[x][y].delete(0, "end")   
    return False
```

Now, `.sleep()` of course doesn't work because it affects the whole GUI. I've noticed that the only thing which seems to work somehow is the `messagebox` widget, but that's not the proper way to deal with it. I've tried also with other widgets, such as hiding some microlabel, but to no avail. What could possibly work?

EDIT1: tried as well with the `.after()` method but couldn't get anything good out of it.

EDIT2: `sudoku[][]` is a list of lists of Entry objects.

EDIT3: [here](https://pastebin.com/z3JVsHGc) you can find a quick very minimal reproducible example of the program.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a complete [mcve] without adding a large number of additional lines of code?

Comment: @BryanOakley: added it in my third edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is call the function update_idletasks on the window when you are doing the sleep so that the widgets in the GUI are updated. Also you will have to declare window as a global variable since it is not in the function.

```
import time
def solve_sudoku():
    global window # Line added for wait
    find = find_empty()
    if not find_empty():
        return True
    else:
        x, y = find
    for num in range(1, 10):
        if validate_cell(x, y, num):
            sudoku[x][y].delete(0, "end")
            sudoku[x][y].insert(0, str(num))
            sudoku[x][y].config(fg = "SpringGreen3")
            time.sleep(0.01) # Line Added for wait
            window.update_idletasks() # Line Added for wait
            if solve_sudoku():
                return True
            sudoku[x][y].delete(0, "end")   
    return False
```